# What is the maximum length of video on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, video

What is the maximum length of video on Facebook? The FAQ offers nothing I could find on maximum file size and/or length of video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook FAQ doesn't list it but currently the limit appears to be 1,024 MB or 20 minutes. Facebook could of course change this in the future.

Comment: The limits will be much lower if your Facebook account is not verified (e.g. with a phone or credit card).

Answer (score 0):

The limit for a non-verified account is 100 MB or 10 minutes.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a reference for either this or the accepted answer, but as it appears to be correct and that is as accurate as the accepted answer, +1